# Keeping all parameters but one constant

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

It is a core scientific principle to only change one of the parameters in an experiment at a time, and keep all others constant, as opposed to picking random parameters (i.e. typically being unable to control the parameters) and performing a factor analysis afterwards.

Is there a short term or phrase to express this concept? I was hoping to find the term in the Wikipedia pages about the [Scientific Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_method#Evaluation_and_improvement) or [experiments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Experiment), but both articles seem to deal in loftier terms.

Comment: Yes; the one parameter you're changing is known as the "independent variable", and the process of fixing the others as best you can is known as "scientific control". The whole shebang is known as a "controlled experiment".

Comment: @DanBron Great, thanks! Can you make that into an answer so that  I can accept and upvote it, or should I?

Comment: I appreciate the offer, but odds are this question is going to be closed as "general reference" (meaning we encourage people to look up such concepts themselves), and answering would contradict that message.

Comment: BTW, for the sake of completeness, I believe the term for parameters you *can't* adequately control is "confounding variables".

Answer (score 4):

This principle is simply called [**scientific control**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_control), wherein one changes the *independent variable* while trying to avoid the influence of *confounding* variables.

Comment: Ha! Well done. +1 from me. Might as well accept your own answer while you're at it.

Comment: @DanBron Sure, will do, [as soon as I'm allowed to](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/55552/141962)

Comment: Cool. Welcome to english.SE!

Comment: Your reputation precedes you.